# New C file creation in freeswitch

Tags: c, module, linker, freeswitch

I am creating new .c file in src/ where other in-built files like switch_core_hash.c and etc. are located. Also I am creating relevant header file in src/include where other in-built .h files are located. Also, I am making relevant changes in src/Makefile.am and src/Makefile.in according to newly creating .c and .h files....

Functions written in .c file created above are called in module say my_module and no error found during compilation of my_module (make and make install)..

During reloading module in fs_cli, below Error is occured "No reference to function"

Comment: `Makefile.in` is a generated file.  Do not modify it directly.  Instead, run `autoreconf` after modifying `Makefile.am`. Or even just let `make` figure out that it needs to run `autoreconf`.

Comment: With that said, I'm not sure why "no reference to function" would be an error, but it seems self-explanatory.  You've not presented any actual code, but I guess you added one or more functions that are never called.